# Can a Creature Avoid an Overrun Attempt by an Unseen Opponent?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

The Overrun maneuver in Pathfinder allows a creature to pass through an enemy's square as part of a charge or move action. If the attacker isn't detected by the target - if it's invisible or just unnoticed - can the target still avoid the Overrun attempt and allow the creature to pass through its space unimpeded, or is the target forced to contest the maneuver?

Comment: Here are other recent questions about the combat maneuver [overrun](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58102/8610) and [making a charge](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58195/8610).

Answer (score 3):

Looking over the rules it doesn't say anything specific, just that the target can choose to avoid or not.  However, it does say that the attacker needs to enter the target's square before the target chooses whether to avoid or resist.  As a GM I would say entering the target's square is enough for the target to notice the invisible attacker.  That being said, I wasn't able to find any additional information either supporting or refuting that.

Comment: I'd like to see anything to back up this answer other than "As a GM I would".

Comment: I don't know why it's getting down-voted. It's perfectly accurate. The game does not say. Offering advice on how to resolve the situation despite an admitted lack of an official rule shouldn't be that bad.