# Can I attack the target of my Overrun?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat-maneuver

Simply put: Can I attack the same creature I choose to use the Overrun combat maneuver on?

The entry for the [Overrun maneuver](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Overrun) states it can be done as part of a charge, does that mean I can attack the target creature after I overrun them at the end of my charge (assuming it is successful)? Or is the charge "attack" spent making the check to move through that creature's space, leaving me unable to attack?

The ideal situation I'm curious about is whether or not I can overrun an opponent, knock them prone, then gain that bonus against them on an attack while potentially setting up for a flank with an ally who can follow after me. I know there is a [feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/elephant-stomp-combat) in one of the Companion books that allows an attacker to knock their target prone, stop *in front* of them and attack with an unarmed strike or natural weapon.

Does the existence of this feat mean that I cannot, rules as written, pass *through* an opponent's square and possibly knock them prone via overrun, and then attack?

Comment: [Man, overrun's a mess.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58102/8610).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I interpret overrun is that it is just allowing you to do your Overrun at any point during a move/charge, but it takes up your standard action or the "attack" that round during the charge (it doesn't give you some free standard action, as is proven by the existence of [Charge Through](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/charge-through-combat), which does).  The [3.5e Overrun](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#overrun) simply said "as a standard action taken during your move", I think the intent of the Pathfinder rule was to just say "during a move, or during a charge, that too."

So you can Overrun someone during a move, or during a charge (double move, +2 to hit, -2 AC). You don't get another standard attack normally, so barring greater overrun or mythic shenanigans, you can't also do a melee attack on them or anyone else - but you can keep on moving past them, which is the special thing this maneuver is trying to give you. You get to bowl over (overrun) someone while on your way to fight someone else with your next round's actions - or, stop and fight them prone, that's fine too, but there's no free attacks/standard actions as part of the base combat maneuver.

Keep in mind the overrun target can choose to get out of the way instead of being overrun, which could let you still attack someone else you were charging at/moving towards.

Comment: So if A charges B yet overruns C who's in A's way and A succeeds in getting past C, A *can* continue the charge to where A's in a position to strike B yet A *can't* then strike B because A overran? Then why *charge* B, suffer the AC penalty and be limited by terrain when a double move would've sufficed? (A charging attacker gets no special bonus to overrunning as he does to, for example, bull rushing.)

Comment: Because C can always choose to just get out of the way and not proc the Overrun. Remember that "When you attempt to overrun a target, it can choose to avoid you." So you really want  to charge B, and either C gets out of the way and you charge and (ideally) hit B, or he stays in the way and you (ideally) trample him and at least get over to your true quarry that round.

Comment: Then the feat [Improved Overrun](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-overrun-combat---final) could be a *hindrance* to creatures wanting to overrun?

Comment: IO is usually a step to some followup power like Greater Overrun or Elephant Stomp or whatever where you actually want the overrun to happen.  I assume someone with IO could still let someone get out of the way if they wanted, but they no longer have to. (You could argue that they can't, RAW, but then you get one of the many issues RAW causes for you, c'est la vie).

Comment: Okay, but that seems a bold supposition for a rules-as-written answer. (I'm really not trying to give you a hard time on this, but I've found the overrun rules a lot murkier than the answer makes them out to be, especially since it assumes that the feat [Charge Through](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/charge-through-combat) actually does anything at all—as per [this thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qb7s?Overrun-with-Charge-Charge-Through-and) and [this thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mb6e?Can-somone-explain-to-me-why-charge-through).)

Comment: I'm not sure that's it's a bold supposition when it's talking about one particular use case (overrunning during a charge, not wanting that guy behind you prone).   "It's better in all cases" is not a reasonable expectation of feats in general, let alone RAW interpretations of feats. Also, you can't double move and overrun, there's no standard action to get from anywhere, by my interpretation.

Comment: In Pathfinder if you have Greater Overrun you get an Attack of Opportunity when they fall prone, as does anyone threatening them.