# What are some other Overrun feat combos?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, combat-maneuver

I am a level 2 Barbarian. I have the Overbearing Advance rage power.

I have the following feats: Power Attack, Improved Overrun.

I am looking into taking the following rage power in the future: Overbearing Onslaught.

I am looking into taking the following feats in the future: Charge Through, Greater Overrun, Combat Reflexes.

What are some additional feats, rage powers, or magic items that combo well with the Overrun special attack?

Comment: Just in case: [the combat maneuver overrun is bit of a mess.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58102/8610) You may want to confirm with the GM that you two are on the same page before committing to it so completely.

Answer (score 1):

## Here are some other related feats to consider

- Spiked Destroyer

  - Gives you an attack with spiked armor as a swift action
  - Requires proficiency in spiked armor
- Vicious Stomp

  - When the opponent falls prone as a result of your overrun, you get an attack of opportunity
  - Requires Combat Reflexes and Improved Unarmed Strike so it takes a bit of work

It is worth noting that you do risk becoming overspecialized as you become much weaker in some encounters where overrun isn't as useful.